# return findViewById() in viewbinding

Tags: java, android, android-viewbinding

I am trying to optimize old code. And I am trying to replace findviewbyid with viewbinding.
But how do I return viewbinding id instead of findviewbyid?

```
private TextView getTextView(int id){
        return (TextView) findViewById(id);
}
```

This is the old code. But I want to apply viewbinding. I want it to work something like this. As I have no idea how to do it.

```
private TextView getTextView(int id){
        return sampleViewBinding(id);
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of View Binding is to avoid `findViewById()` calls. It does it for you automatically. What you are trying to do is treating View Binding like `findViewById()`. Whenever you need to access any view, all you have to do it call the generated binding class with your id in the camel-case. for e.g `main_layout.xml` is gonna have a class generated by the name `MainLayoutBinding` so you are going to access all the view inside your layout by calling the `MainLayoutBinding`'s instance and the id you want to access.

Answer (score 0):

If your layout file name is `fragment_dashboard.xml` and has within a textview with an Id `userNameTvId`, then you normally do this without using data binding:

```
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)
val textview = view.findViewById(R.id.userNameTvId)
```

but with `viewBinding` it is done by chaining. this textview is acceptable through the binding object. The above will be rewritten like this using `viewBinding`:

```
val binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater)
binding.userNameTvId

// to pass a value you can just do
binding.userNameTvId = "SomeOne"

val view = binding.root
```